# undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()

Tags: unix, boost

I am trying to include boost in my project.
It is giving me error

> server.cpp:(.text+0x200): undefined reference to
>   `boost::system::generic_category()'
>
> server.cpp:(.text+0x20a): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'

I have linked `libboost_system`

```
g++44 -I/include /lib/libboost_chrono.a /lib/libboost_date_time.a \
/lib/libboost_exception.a /lib/libboost_filesystem.a /lib/libboost_graph.a \
/lib/libboost_iostreams.a /lib/libboost_locale.a /lib/libboost_math_c99.a \
/lib/libboost_math_c99f.a /lib/libboost_math_c99l.a /lib/libboost_math_tr1.a \
/lib/libboost_math_tr1f.a /lib/libboost_math_tr1l.a /lib/libboost_program_options.a \
/lib/libboost_python.a /lib/libboost_random.a /lib/libboost_regex.a \
/lib/libboost_serialization.a /lib/libboost_signals.a /lib/libboost_system.a \
/lib/libboost_thread.a /lib/libboost_timer.a /lib/libboost_wave.a \
/lib/libboost_wserialization.a \
-m32 -lrt server.cpp -o server.exe
```

Comment: check the order of the libraries... Or just show the compile/link commands...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is you're not specifying your source before the libraries:

```
g++44 -I/include -m32 -lrt server.cpp -o server.exe /lib/libboost_chrono.a /lib/libboost_date_time.a \
/lib/libboost_exception.a /lib/libboost_filesystem.a /lib/libboost_graph.a \
/lib/libboost_iostreams.a /lib/libboost_locale.a /lib/libboost_math_c99.a \
/lib/libboost_math_c99f.a /lib/libboost_math_c99l.a /lib/libboost_math_tr1.a \
/lib/libboost_math_tr1f.a /lib/libboost_math_tr1l.a /lib/libboost_program_options.a \
/lib/libboost_python.a /lib/libboost_random.a /lib/libboost_regex.a \
/lib/libboost_serialization.a /lib/libboost_signals.a /lib/libboost_system.a \
/lib/libboost_thread.a /lib/libboost_timer.a /lib/libboost_wave.a \
/lib/libboost_wserialization.a
```

Also, there's likely no reason to link every boost library archive ever willed into existence

Comment: Cheers :) Next time, search [tag:c++-faq] and try to include relevant information in your question!